# Android to php send UTF8 encode text, not working with cyrillic or arabic characteres

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, cyrillic

I need to send a String from Android to a php web service (user input in a EditText).
This run ok, with standars characteres, and some special chars (like accents, ñ and more), but when I send cyrillic or arabic chars, the web service do not recognize then, and replace by other chars (like Â±ÐÒ).
This is my Android code:

```
// Post the data:
public class Sincronizar extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject> {
    String resFromServer=null;
    private String url = "http://.../send.php"; //The url of the web service
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(JSONObject... data) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            JSONObject jsonPlace = new JSONObject();
            jsonPlace.put("pais", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTexto)).getText().toString());
            JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
            postjson.put(jsonPlace);

            // Post the data:
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
            httppost.setHeader("json",jsonPlace.toString());
            httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response.getEntity()!=null) {
                resFromServer = org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
                jsonResponse=new JSONObject(resFromServer);
            } 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.e("Sincronizar","doIn:"+resFromServer);
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResponse) {
        try{
            if (jsonResponse!=null) {
                String pais = jsonResponse.getString("pais");
                String respuesta = String.format("PAIS: %s",pais);
                Log.e("Sincronizar",""+respuesta);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText(respuesta);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Sincronizar","onPostExecute: "+e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onPostExecute(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

And this is the php web service:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
try {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'])) {
    $json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
    $cadena = utf8_encode($json);
    $data = json_decode($cadena,true);
    $json_error= json_last_error();
    $pais = $data["pais"];  
} else {
    $pais="No received";
}
}catch(Exception $e) {
    $pais="Exception: ".$e->getMessage();
}
$output=array('pais'=>$pais);
print(utf8_encode(json_encode($output)));
?>
```

In the web service I also try to insert the String received to a Mysql DB. The normal and some special chars like Ñ, á (accents), etc., are received e inserted ok. But with the arabic or cyrillic chars I receive this kind of Strings: "±±´" , "±Ã´À"

I think the problem is the encoding, but I send and receive UTF8 (I think)
Any idea?
thanks!

Comment: What is the collation in the database?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Before Sql opeatrion on server in php run

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")
```

(or equivalent, I used mysqli)
This solved my problem

```
mysqli_set_charset($con,'utf8');
mysqli_query($con, "insert into table (name, lastname) values ('Ñishá', 'Akopov')");
```

You can write select statement and retrieve rows in utf8

hope this will help

Comment: Cool! It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this function this may help you

```
function parseUtf8ToIso88591($string){
     if(!is_null($string)){
            $iso88591_1 = utf8_decode($string);
            $iso88591_2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $string);
            $string = mb_convert_encoding($string, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');  
            return "";
     }
     return $string;
}
```